# Drupal - relate taxonomy terms with users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and I try to add tags to my site's users. I see that I could [relate any content node with taxonomy terms](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy), but I cannot find a way to **relate users with taxonomy terms**.

I thought that maybe I could build a custom content type and relate this with the specific taxonomy. But even then, I cannot add a field to the custom content type referencing a user.

I cannot believe that drupal is missing such a feature. What am I missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right. Drupal includes such functionality. Following the "admin-->Configuration-->Account Settings-->Manage fields" path, **drupal allows to add fields to user accounts**. There, I can relate my user accounts with taxonomy terms or other content types.

I hope this answer will be useful to others.